# Java. Why can i pass an object argument, if in the method definition the arguments are the type of an interface?

Tags: java, oop, return, arguments, throw

Let's say I have the following interface:

```
public interface Numeric
{
    public Numeric addition(Numeric x,Numeric y);
}
```

And the following class:

```
public class Complex implements Numeric
{
    private int real;
    private int img;

    public Complex(int real, int img){
        this.real = real;
        this.img = img;
    }

    public Numeric addition(Numeric x, Numeric y){
        if (x instanceof Complex && y instanceof Complex){
            Complex n1 = (Complex)x;
            Complex n2 = (Complex)y;

            return new Complex(n1.getReal() + n1.getReal(), n2.getImg() + 
            n2.getImg()); 

        } throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public int getReal(){
        return real;
    }

    public int getImg(){
        return img;
    }
}
```

I have a couple questions:

1. The addition method has the return type Numeric, and it's arguments
   are Numeric. x and y are then verified if they are of type Complex.
   But how can I pass Complex arguments, when in the definition the
   arguments are of type Numeric? The same when I return. I return a
   Complex object, not Numeric. What is the correlation and logic
   behind this.
2. If x and y are Complex, because I checked in the if, why do I need to cast x and y to new 2 objects?
   What is the point of casting, if they are already Complex.
3. And why the if doesn't work without the throw? What does `UnsupportedOperationException` is, and why is it mandatory?

Comment: Please google "java oop polymorphism" and work through a couple of tutorials, e.g. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_polymorphism.htm . Regarding 3: what if `x` and `y` are not `Complex`? What would the method return? Btw: it is **VERY** bad practice since it breaks the Liskov Substitution Principle (LSP) (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860/what-is-an-example-of-the-liskov-substitution-principle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As `Complex` implements `Numeric`, any `Complex` object can be used wherever `Numeric` is expected.
2. Every `Numeric` object is not `Complex`. There can be another class `Real` where `Real implements Numeric`. In this case, a `Numeric` variable can be referencing a `Real` object and you cannot substitute a `Real` object with `Complex`. So, you need to cast the object.
3. As return type of method `addition` is `Numeric`, your code MUST be returning an object of type `Numeric`. In case you remove throw statement and if condition is evaluated to false, method will not return anything and compiler will complain.